# Buddypress update user avatar image via REST

Tags: php, rest-api, buddypress, avatar

I’m creating a custom back-end API to update a user avatar image via user id. So i send via post REST request this parameters:

– `user_id` : The id of the user;

– image: `base64` image;

– `image_name`: the image name.

This is the php code that i use to update the avatar image but it doesn’t works

```
// Get URL data
global $json_api
$user_id = $json_api->query->user_id;
$image = $json_api->query->image;
$image_name = $json_api->query->image_name;
$image = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$hashed_filename = md5( $image_name . microtime() ) . '_bpthumb.jpg';
$data = base64_decode($image);
$success = file_put_contents('/wp-content/uploads/avatars/'.$user_id.'/'.$hashed_filename, $data);
```

`$success` variable returns always false T.T

Thank you in advance for the help and sorry for my english.

Comment: Try https://github.com/buddypress/BP-REST

Comment: @shagebp Thank you for reply but BP-REST doesn't help me :( i've found at this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107700/uploade-user-image-in-wordpress-using-json-api?newreg=3805f3d2be8141ef925dc600fa73afa7) a code that seems to work but i've some problem if i change the path of the avatar image from `file_put_contents($uploaddir["path"].'/'.$avatar,$imgdata);` to `file_put_contents($uploaddir["path"].'/'.$user_id.'/'.$avatar,$imgdata);`

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a SOLUTION and i want to post it because can be useful for someone!

```
public function update_user_avatar() 
{
   global $json_api;
   if (!$json_api->query->user_id) 
   {
      $json_api->error("Missing 'user_id' parameter.");
   }
   if (!$json_api->query->image) 
   {
     $json_api->error("Missing 'image' parameter.");
   }
   $user_id = $json_api->query->user_id;
   $base64 = $json_api->query->image;

   $imgdata            =   base64_decode($base64);
   $f = finfo_open();
   $mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
   $type_file = explode('/', $mime_type);
   $time = time();
   $avatar_thumb = $time . '-bpthumb.' . $type_file[1];
   $avatar_full = $time . '-bpfull.' . $type_file[1];

   $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir(); 
   $myDirPath = $uploaddir["path"]; 
   $myDirUrl = $uploaddir["url"];
   $upload_path = '/home/<folder>/public_html/wp-content/uploads/avatars/'.$user_id;

   // Create user id folder if not exist for avatar image
   if (!file_exists($upload_path)) 
   {
       mkdir($upload_path, 0755, true);
   }
   require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php');             
   require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/file.php');
   require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/image.php');

   // Remove files into user's folder
   $files = list_files($upload_path);
   for($i = 0; $i<count($files); $i++)
   {
     wp_delete_file($files[$i]);
   }

   file_put_contents($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_thumb,$imgdata);
   file_put_contents($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_full,$imgdata);
   switch ($type_file[1]) {
     case 'jpeg':
       # code...
       $img_full = $this->resize_imagejpg($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_full, 150, 150);
       $img_thumb = $this->resize_imagejpg($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_thumb, 50, 50);
       break;
     case 'jpg':
       # code...
       $img_full = $this->resize_imagejpg($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_full, 150, 150);
       $img_thumb = $this->resize_imagejpg($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_thumb, 50, 50);
       break;
     case 'png':
       # code...
       $img_full = $this->resize_imagepng($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_full, 150, 150);
       $img_thumb = $this->resize_imagepng($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_thumb, 50, 50);
       break;
     case 'gif':
       # code...
       $img_full = $this->resize_imagegif($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_full, 150, 150);
       $img_thumb = $this->resize_imagegif($upload_path.'/'.$avatar_thumb, 50, 50);
       break;
     default:
        return array(
               "success" => false,
               "avatar_url" => get_avatar_url($user_id));
        break;
   }
   // Override previous image
   imagejpeg($img_thumb, $$upload_path.'/'.$avatar_full, 100);
   imagejpeg($img_full, $upload_path.'/'.$avatar_thumb);

   $filename = $myDirUrl.'/'.basename( $avatar_thumb );
   $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
   $uploadfile = $upload_path.'/'. basename( $filename );           
   $attachment = array(
      "post_mime_type" => $wp_filetype["type"],
      "post_title" => preg_replace("/\.[^.]+$/", "" , basename( $filename )),
      "post_content" => "",
      "post_status" => "inherit",
      'guid' => $uploadfile,
   );              


   $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

   update_post_meta($attachment_id,'_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar',$user_id);
   update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_user_avatar', $attachment_id);
   return array(
     "success" => true,
     "avatar_url_thumb" => get_avatar_url($user_id),
     "avatar_url_full" => $this->get_avatar_url_full($user_id));
 }
```

These are methods to resize the image (Code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php):

```
 // for jpg 
  private function resize_imagejpg($file, $w, $h) {
     list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
     $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
     $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
     imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
     return $dst;
  }

   // for png
  private function resize_imagepng($file, $w, $h) {
     list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
     $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
     $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
     imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
     return $dst;
  }

  // for gif
  private function resize_imagegif($file, $w, $h) {
     list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
     $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
     $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
     imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
     return $dst;
  }
```

This is a function that i wrote to retrieve the full avatar image url:

```
private function get_avatar_url_full($user_id)
{
    require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php');             
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/image.php');
    $upload_path = '/home/<folder>/public_html/wp-content/uploads/avatars/'.$user_id;
    $files = list_files($upload_path);
    if (count($files) == 0 || count($files) == 1)
    {
        return get_avatar_url($user_id);
    }
    else
    {
      for($i = 0; $i<count($files); $i++)
      {
        if(strpos($files[$i], '-bpfull.'))
        {
          $avatar_full_name = explode('/', $files[$i]);
          $url = htmlspecialchars("https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/");
          return $url.$user_id.'/'.$avatar_full_name[count($avatar_full_name)-1];
        }
      }
      return get_avatar_url($user_id);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I piggybacked on your solution (particularly the naming convention) for my approach to the problem of programmatically updating the avatar from an external URL: https://gist.github.com/bookchiq/2a8f85efe6fd46a7df33b2dba899fd00